# Using function return values for choices option at Symfony2 form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have this Symfony2 form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add(
            'nombre',
            'text',
            array(
                'required' => true,
                'mapped'   => false,
                'label'    => 'Nombre'
            )
        )
        ->add(
            'anno_modelo',
            'choice',
            array(
                'placeholder'   => 'Escoja una opción',
                'choices'       => array(),
                'required'      => true
            )
        )
        ->add(
            'anno_fabricacion',
            'choice',
            array(
                'placeholder'   => 'Escoja una opción',
                'choices'       => array(),
                'required'      => true
            )
        );
}
```

and I have this code:

```
function getChoices() {
    $choices = [];
    for($i = date("Y"); $ >= 1900; $i--) {
        $choices[$i - 1] = $i - 1;
    }

    return $choices;
}
```

I need to use that `$choices` as a `choices` value, how I can achieve that?

Comment: A side note but an easier way of creating that would be to use the range function like `$range = range(date('Y'), 1900);` to get the range of years and then return it with the same keys as values using array_combine like `return array_combine($range, $range);`.

Comment: @Qoop a valid example, thanks, this is just a example function since the one I'm working on is a bit complicated and I not finished yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $choices = $this->getChoices();
    $builder
        ->add(
            'nombre',
            'text',
            array(
                'required' => true,
                'mapped'   => false,
                'label'    => 'Nombre'
            )
        )
        ->add(
            'anno_modelo',
            'choice',
            array(
                'placeholder'   => 'Escoja una opción',
                'choices'       => $choices,
                'required'      => true
            )
        )
        ->add(
            'anno_fabricacion',
            'choice',
            array(
                'placeholder'   => 'Escoja una opción',
                'choices'       => $choices,
                'required'      => true
            )
        );
}

private function getChoices() 
{
    $choices = [];
    for($i = date('Y'); $i >= 1900; $i--) {
        $choices[$i - 1] = $i - 1;
    }

    return $choices;
}
```